# Unable to read Graphml in networkx which was already written by networkx nx.write_graphml

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I write a graphml file using nx.write_graphml but when i try to read it back i get the folllowing error

```
>>> g = nx.DiGraph()
>>> g = nx.read_graphml('cit89.graphml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_graphml
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 220, in _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 153, in read_graphml
    glist=list(reader(path=path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 405, in __call__
    yield self.make_graph(g, keys, defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 431, in make_graph
    self.add_node(G, node_xml, graphml_keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 456, in add_node
    node_id = self.node_type(node_xml.get("id"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please provide the file you are trying to read, or a short self-contained example that produces the error.

Comment: the file contains node ids like <node id="JosÃ© M. F. Moura" /> <node id="Jean VÃ©ronis" />  <node id="HervÃ© Da Costa" /> <node id="Jochen DÃ¶rre" />  <node id="David S. BrÃ©e" />
    <node id="Jean-Claude HervÃ©" />  and many more about 2*10^5 and a million edges ..........plz help

Comment: Maybe you can trim it down to a small complete example that shows the problem? Obviously there is some problems with character encodings.